# Jquery mobile dialog doesn't scroll with dynamic content

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

When I dynamically add content to a jQuery mobile dialog, and the new content extends beyond the bottom edge of my phone's screen, I cannot scroll the dialog down to see the new content. However, when I rotate my device to force a redraw of whatever's on the screen, scrolling down works fine.

I tried .page() and .trigger('create') on the dialog element and the element inside the dialog to which the new content is appended - doesn't fix the problem.

How can I update my dialog so scrolling works across all content that has been added to it?

I'm using Jquery mobile 1.2.0, Phonegap 2.2.0, Android 4.0.

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using a jquery mobile listview in my dialog. Adding dynamic content to that works with scrolling. But I haven't figured out how to get other kinds of dynamic content (<div>'s for example) to work properly in JQM dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the redraw that makes scrolling start working when you rotate the screen. jQuery mobile has a window resize event that sets the page size in pixels, which sometimes leads to size changes at the wrong time. In most cases you can override that with an !important rule in the css.

If you don't want to dig into jQuery mobile internals, an easier option may be to put a fixed size container inside the dialog and set overflow:auto on that so that the dialog itself doesn't need to scroll.

Comment: I can't use a fixed size container as I don't know what the absolute size of the dialog will be, and I'm not that keen on use a CSS workaround. Besides, the dialog should be scrollable without being dependent on how it's content is styled. It scrolls fine for the content added on the first dynamic update. The error occurs only when attempting to update it again.

Comment: You need to get used to ugly workarounds when trying to get a mobile app to look perfect, especially on Android. Note that the scroll container can be fixed relative to the dialog rather than absolutely - the key is that it is a container that is controlled by your css rather than the jqm dialog setup code.

Answer (score 0):

[.trigger('updatelayout')](https://api.jquerymobile.com/updatelayout/) fixed this problem for me, both in Chrome/webkit and on iOS.

I invoke it every time I append new content e.g:

```
jQuery("#" + id).append(paragraph).trigger('updatelayout');
```